# Avoid outlining inline modules (keep inline modules) in inputs

Tags: vite

I couldn't find an option to avoid moving inline modules into separate modules in Vite.

index.html:

```
<script type="module">
...
</script>
```

Vite converts this to a separate module file (at least in dev mode). Is it possible to keep inline modules inline?